# Using Flutter, how can I automatically display an email that has been updated in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have an account page that has an update button which updates the user's email.  This functionality is fine, however, I can't get the page to show the updated email without refreshing the app manually (after the few seconds it takes for the email to be updated in firebase).  I have gone down a rabbit hole with StreamBuilder, Timer, but what I can't figure out is how to retrieve the updated email from firebase without having to refresh the page.  Ideally I would wait for the email to be updated in firebase, a CircularProgressIndicator show up while I wait, then have the Account page back showing the updated email.

```
void changeEmail(User user, BuildContext context) {
    final myController = TextEditingController();

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Update Email')),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: [
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              Text('Please enter a new email: '),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                      controller: myController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'New Email')))
            ]),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Don\'t Change'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () => setState(
                        () {
                          var newEmail = myController.text;
                          if (EmailValidator.validate(newEmail)) {
                            user.changeEmail(newEmail);
// Here is where something needs to happen
                            Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => AccountPage()));
                          } else {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text('Invalid Email.'),
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        FlatButton(
                                            child: Text('Close'),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            })
                                      ]);
                                });
                          }
                        },
                      ))
            ])
          ])),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

The Stateful AccountPage Widget:

```
class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar('Settings'),
        drawer: BuildDrawer(),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            pageTitle(),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                rowBuilder('Username: ', 'Email :', user, context),
                FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Change Password'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      changePassword(user, context);
                    }),
                FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    child: Text('Remove Account Data'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      deleteData(context);
                    })
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: If you have an email field in firebase database then you could listen to ```snapshots``` if it's in ```Firestore``` or ```onValue```if it's in ```RealtimeDB```. If you are changing email in ```FirebaseAuth``` then you need to ```reload``` the firebase User

Comment: can you tell me how your data look like where you are updating email?

Comment: Hi Jagraj thanks for your comment, it looks like this may be a common flutter issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20390   I may try to solve the problem by looking into using https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_user_stream

Comment: I was facing the exact problem in my previous projects, What I did was calling ```reload```  on the previous user and again calling ```currentUser```. BTW thanks for the above links. Helped me a lot.